# C# Dynamically Generate Queues

Tags: c#

I have a class called "BatteryPack:"

```
public class BatteryPack
{


    public string BatteryType;
    public int BatteryCount


}
```

I want to organize the packs into queues based on `BatteryType`, so that I can take batteries from one pack in a type, and then move to a different pack and take some from that.

The problem is, I don't know how many different battery types I have until runtime, so I can't make the queues beforehand. Is there a way for me to generate queues at runtime, or is there another way to solve this problem while allowing me to maintain a distinct place in the list?

Comment: Have you looked into using an `array` or `List<T>`? A `List` can be created dynamically, which is what I would recommend since you don't know the different types until runtime

Comment: "Is there a way for me to generate queues at runtime..." Yeah, it's `new Queue()`.

Comment: @Kenneth I think it’s obvious that wasn’t the part of the question I was having trouble with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

```
Dictionary<string, Queue<BatteryPack>> TypeToPack = new Dictionary<string, Queue<BatteryPack>>();

foreach(BatteryPack pack in BatteryPacks)
{
    if(!TypeToPack.ContainsKey(pack.BatteryType))
        TypeToPack.Add(pack.BatteryType, new Queue<BatteryPack>());

    TypeToPack[pack.BatteryType].Enqueue(pack);
}
```